# Array Mapping and Filtering ReactJs

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I have two(2) arrays, `beforeArray` & `afterArray`

```
const beforeArray = [
   {
    id:1, 
    name:'Alice'
   },
   {
    id:2, 
    name:'Rabbit'
   },
   {
    id:3, 
    name:'Queen'
   },
   {
    id:4, 
    name:'King'
   },
];

const afterArray = [
   {
    id:3, 
    name:'Queen'
   },
];
```

I'm trying to get the difference of `beforeArray` & `afterArray` like this array below:

```
const currentArray = [
   {
    id:1, 
    name:'Alice'
   },
   {
    id:2, 
    name:'Rabbit'
   },
   {
    id:4, 
    name:'King'
   },
];
```

I tried using these way but it only returns the value from `let currentArray = [];`:

```
let currentArray = [];

await afterArray.map(async item => {
    await beforeArray.filter(async find => {
        if (item.id != find.id) {
            await currentArray.map(async less => {
                if (less.id == find.id) {
                    return;
                } else {
                    currentArray = await [...currentArray, find];
                }
            });
        }
    })

console.log(currentArray);
```

I think it `console.log(currentArray)` skips the `await`....
How can I get the value from the awaited map and filter?

Comment: based on the name property are you trying to find the difference ? what is the rule for finding difference ?

Comment: What is with all the `async` and `await`s? I don't think any of this is async code.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get the difference between two arrays in Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1187518/how-to-get-the-difference-between-two-arrays-in-javascript)

Comment: @KunalMukherjee I'm trying to remove the `{id:3, name:'Queen'}` from the `beforeArray` and pass it on to the `currentArray`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You should not be using the async/await until you want to wait for a promise to get resolved.

You can filter array using [Array.prototype.filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) and [Array.prototype.find](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find)

```js
const beforeArray = [
 {
  id:1, 
  name:'Alice'
 },
 {
  id:2, 
  name:'Rabbit'
 },
 {
  id:3, 
  name:'Queen'
 },
 {
  id:4, 
  name:'King'
 },
];

const afterArray = [
 {
  id:3, 
  name:'Queen'
 },
];

let out = beforeArray.filter(({id, name}) => !afterArray.find(r => r.id === id && r.name === name));

console.log(out)
```

Answer (score 2):

Try filtering the array using `Array.prototype.some` like this:

```js
const beforeArray = [{
    id: 1,
    name: 'Alice'
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: 'Rabbit'
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    name: 'Queen'
  },
  {
    id: 4,
    name: 'King'
  },
];

const afterArray = [{
  id: 3,
  name: 'Queen'
}];

const currentArray = beforeArray.filter(x => {
  return afterArray.some(y => y.id !== x.id && y.name !== x.name);
});

console.log(currentArray);
```